# How to rotate element around his center?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have an element.
And I want to rotate it, using JS.

It works, but it rotates around other points.

I need to rotate it around its own center.
How do I do this?

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var a = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('.section-4 .photo .after').css('transform', 'rotate('+ (a / 10) +'deg)');
});
```

Comment: The `rotate()` rule *does* rotate around the center point of the element. Why do you believe that it is not in your case? You may need to set the width and height of the element. A working example would help here.

Comment: transform-origin: center

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS3 feature:

```
transform-origin: center
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class = "rotateDiv"></div>
<img src = "http://static-note-i-1.heartynote.com/img/icons/head_logo.png">
<style>
img{
transform: rotate(160deg);
}
```